# Use one batch file and qsub to run multiple MATLAB program in parallel

Tags: matlab, batch-file, command, hpc, qsub

I need to run the same `script_1` in `folder1`, `folder2`, `folder3`, ..., `folder` with MATLAB command mode in cluster.

I used qsub to submit the batch into the compute node. However, it turnes out there was a limit to the number of jobs each user could submit. Thus, I need to come up with a way to run the `script_1` in different folder in a single batch job.

Something like:

```
cd ../
cd ~/folder1
matlab -r script1
cd ../
cd ~/folder2
matlab -r script1
cd ../
cd ~/folder3
matlab -r script1
cd ../
cd ~/folder4
matlab -r script1
cd ../
cd ~/folder5
matlab -r script1
cd ../
```

However, this batch was shown as "serial", and it needed to run in `folder2` until the code in folder1 was finished.

Is there a way to run the `script1` in different folders together in a single batch job?

Comment: Add an `&` at the end of the line that starts a MATLAB job. This makes the job run in the background.

Comment: Use `for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /B /AD "folder*"') do start "" "matlab" -r %%~fA\script1`.